# Can an integrable system not have a lagrangian?

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation

It is known that some systems are non-integrable, but have a Lagrangian, e.g. the 3-body orbit problem. Now considering the converse, is there an example of an integrable system that does not have a Lagrangian (does not need to be a mechanical system)?

This may be unrelated, but I know that systems that are not self-adjoint generally do not have a Lagrangian.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "integrable system", see [Exactly solvable models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system#Exactly_solvable_models) and [Can one write down a Hamiltonian in the absence of a Lagrangian?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/231750/65263) on Physics SE.

Comment: I don't understand this well so not sure if it helps but the other day I came across a [post](https://motls.blogspot.com/2017/11/competent-formal-theorists-know-they.html) that discuss about when you don't have a lagrangian but it doesn't speaks about integrability although.